# powershell invoke-webrequest websession not set for react pages?

Tags: reactjs, powershell

I try to set the session when accessing a react page. In my sample code below I use facebook as an example

```
$url = "https://facebook.com" 
$webrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable websession 

Write-Output $websession

$cookies = $websession.Cookies.GetCookies($url) 

# Here, you can output all of $cookies, or you can go through them one by one. 

foreach ($cookie in $cookies) { 
     # You can get cookie specifics, or just use $cookie 
     # This gets each cookie's name and value 
     Write-Host "$($cookie.name) = $($cookie.value)" 
}
```

(script taken from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Getting-Cookies-using-3c373c7e )

That does not output any cookie, although FB sends cookies as I can see in the browser's developer console. If I run this script on google.ch it works. I also tried with another react page and again... does not work. What am I am missing here?

best regards

Comment: Whats this have to do with ReactJS? I ran the script above and i got the cookies.

Comment: Hm. I am just trying to see a pattern, hence my guess was react. I don't get cookies back. If I run this with facebook, I getan empty cookie container. With Google, I get cookies back. I also tried this from a different network now... same result. Weird. What is the difference between your setup and mine? Any clue? My powershell version is

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  547     

My Windows version:

`Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      16299  0       
`
Maybe any difference here?